# Modify tuple elements in a nested recursion for inplace updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have nested data structures composed of dict, list, tuple combinations, with leaves can be safely assumed to be numpy arrays. For example, this is a simple one level nesting:

```
x = [
    {'x': np.arange(3)}, 
    {'y': np.arange(10), 'z': np.arange(4)}, 
    np.array([0.1]),
    (np.array([1.1, 2.2]), np.arange(2))
]
```

I have a recursive function which walks through the nested data structure returns the leaf element, waits for input and updates the element in-place. Here's the code which uses coroutines:

```
def walk(x, update=False):
    for i, key in enumerate(x):
        value = x[key] if isinstance(x, dict) else key

        if isinstance(value, (dict, list, tuple)):
            yield from walk(value, update=update)
        else:
            result = yield value
            
            if update:
                if isinstance(x, dict):
                    x[key] = result
                elif isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
                    x[i] = result
```

So this works fine, except when I have a tuple, where I get error, as expected, for the assignment operation `x[i] = result` because tuples are immutable.

I am hoping to find a solution to this preferably without completely changing existing code, but open to any solution.

Maybe using a numpy in-place function like `x[i].modify(result)` if there's one, since leaves are numpy arrays. Or maybe is there a simple way to temporary modify tuple to list for the update. I appreciate any ideas/solutions!

Answer (score 1):

If the leaves are always numpy arrays you can write

```
elif isinstance(x, tuple):
    x[i][:] = result
```

to replace the contents of the numpy array in-place.

Comment: Yess! I knew there's something I'm forgetting. thank you!

Comment: ah... this doesn't work if array shape changes... :(

Comment: @Gerges Sadly I don't think you can change the array shape in-place.

Comment: adding `x[i].resize(result.shape, refcheck=False)` before this does look like it solves the problem.

Comment: @Gerges That is likely going into dangerous territory but maybe it works for you, I can't say.

Comment: I agree, this may not be a great solution